# Querying a varbinary column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some issues with querying `varbinary` columns using the `contains` predicate (it only works on `nvarchar/varchar` but on the msdn documentation it is specified that it works on `image/varbinary` also)

I have this table

```
[dbo].[Documents]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [doctype] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [docexcerpt] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [doccontent] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

- `doctype` - document type (format)
- `docexcerpt` - small fragment of the document
- `doccontent` - whole document stored in varbinary

Code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Documents (title, doctype, docexcerpt, doccontent)
   SELECT 
      N'Columnstore Indices and Batch Processing',
      N'docx',
      N'You should use a columnstore index on your fact tables, putting all columns of a fact table in a columnstore index. In addition to fact tables, very large dimensions could benefit from columnstore indices as well. Do not use columnstore indices for small dimensions. ',
      bulkcolumn
   FROM 
      OPENROWSET(BULK 'myUrl', SINGLE_BLOB) AS doc;
```

Now this is how it looks like :

[image]

I have installed the Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs and registered them in SQL Server and checked if what I need (`.docx`) is installed using

```
SELECT document_type, path
FROM sys.fulltext_document_types;
```

Here's the output

[image]

My issue is that this query doesn't return anything :

[image]

As an observation, I have created a fulltext catalog and index on my table using the following code(s), making both `docexcerpt` and `doccontent` index-able columns

```
--fulltext index
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Documents
(
    docexcerpt Language 1033,
    doccontent TYPE COLUMN doctype Language 1033
    STATISTICAL_SEMANTICS
)
KEY INDEX PK_Documents
ON DocumentsFtCatalog
WITH STOPLIST = SQLStopList,
SEARCH PROPERTY LIST = WordSearchPropertyList,
CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong/missing. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to 'solve' the mistery, well.... I forgot that I had to re-insert my documents into my tables (after editing them) in order for my queries to work properly. Can't believe I've been so numb.